# Exposing Meteor to Global namespace

Tags: node.js, meteor

Using Meteor I used to be able to open up the console and directly call Meteor methods.

```
console.log(Meteor.userId())
```

Now I get a reference error that Meteor is not defined. How do I go about exposing the Meteor object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just open console and refresh the page (with console open), then `Meteor` will be available

Comment: Wow, so simple. Did they document that somewhere?

Comment: I haven't seen info about this trick in the documentation. But maybe it is written somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do `var Meteor = require('meteor/meteor').Meteor;` in the console to access `Meteor`.

Comment: Nope, 
     Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined(…)

Comment: Alright, my bad. Then the problem (with `require` as well as `Meteor`) can be solved with imkost's answer.